# Cannot find Google Maps key

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I realize that this may be a moot question, and it may not be possible to find what I am asking, but here goes nothing.

I would like to find the API key or its location in code/database which is being used by Google Maps on my website.

It's a WordPress website, and I am currently using a theme called Directory Engine from Engine Themes.

Please [see the URL.](https://www.matterhornlaw.com/law%20firm/freshfields-bruckhaus-deringer-worldwide/)

The map block shows an error, after initially loading for a second. 
I have used different plugins, even combed through the code to figure out where it could be, but couldn't

I know this is a long shot, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you sign up with an API key for google maps? if not [do it here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) most templates/plugins do not include the api key you are expected to use your own.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this. `//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;signed_in=false&amp;ver=1` this is the API call on your page. Obviously you should try to find out where this is in your code as you are not passing an API key and make use of deprecated parameters (`signed_in` and `sensor`) see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required) for more info. The `ver=1` parameter doesn't correspond to any parameter I know.

Comment: I have tried looking almost every where, but I cannot seem to find the API key that's currently being used. I inherited this site from a previous developer who has gone underground. I tried incorporating the <script> tags in the header, but the console just shows that I have used Google Maps API key several times, and doesn't display the map.

Comment: @MrUpsidown would you have any idea as to where Wordpress would store API keys, in the DB?

Comment: No idea. You have to find where the API call is made and there you should be able to see where the key comes from. Could be full text in the script API call, or in a variable (db), could be injected by a specific module, etc. Search your admin backend for a Google Maps menu, search the entire code for the call to the API. If it's there, it's there. But I can't tell you where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the following URL and generate a key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

in your code replace the following link.

//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&signed_in=false&ver=1&key=YOUR_GENERATE_KEY

after that, your issue will be fixed.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly use the google maps api you must include YOUR_API_KEY in the code

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"
    async defer>
</script>
```

your code has

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&signed_in=false&ver=1">
</script>
```

sign up for your own API key [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) and place that in the code above

**Search your code base**

if you are having trouble locating where in your code base the api is set you could try to use a command line script on your root folder

```
grep -r "googleapis"
```

**Search your Database**

you could try to do a `sql dump` then search that file for the string

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for.

Comment: @happymacarts, I have signed up for the Maps Api key, but I cannot find the key in the script, which is causing this. Your method would've worked, if it weren't for the already existing, but hard to locate API key thats being used right now. Thank you though!

Comment: Here is another thought... Do you have command line access? you could `grep -r "googleapis"` to see what comes up